# Multiple Java projects and refactoring

Tags: java, refactoring, package, packaging

I have recently joined a project that is using multiple different projects. A lot of these projects are depending on each other, using JAR files of the other project included in a library, so anytime you change one project, you have to then know which other projest use it and update them too. I would like to make this much easier, and was thinking about merging all this java code into one project in seperate packages. Is it possible to do this and then deploy only some of the packages in a jar. I would like to not deploy only part of it but have been sassked if this is possible.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Approach 1: Using Hudson

If you use a continuous integration server like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/), then you can configure upstream/downstream projects (see [Terminology](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Terminology)).

> A project can have one or several downstream projcets. The downstream projects are added to the build queue if the current project is built successfully. It is possible to setup that it should add the downstream project to the call queue even if the current project is unstable (default is off).

What this means is, if someone checks in some code into one project, at least you would get early warning if it broke other builds.

#### Approach 2: Using Maven

If the projects are not too complex, then perhaps you could create a main project, and make these sub-projects child modules of this project. However, mangling a project into a form that Maven likes can be quite tricky.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Eclipse (or any decent IDE) you can just make one project depend on another, and supply that configuration aspect in your SVN, and assume checkouts in your build scripts.

Note that if one project depends on a certain version of another project, the Jar file is a far simpler way to manage this. A major refactoring could immediately means lots of work in all the other projects to fix things, whereas you could just drop the new jar in to each project as required and do the migration work then.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it probably all depends on the specific project, but I think I would keep all the projects separate.  This help keep the whole system loosely coupled.  You can use a tool such as [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to help manage all the dependencies between the projects.  Managing dependencies like this is one of maven's main strengths.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ant as your build tool, you can package your project any way that you want.  However, leaving parts of your code out of the distribution seems like it would be error prone; you might accidentally leave out necessary classes (presumably, all of your classes are necessary).

In relation to keeping your code in different projects, I have a loose guideline.  Keep the code that changes together in the same project and package it in its own jar file.  This works best when some of your code can be broken out into utility libraries that change less frequently than your main application.

For example, you might have an application where you've generated web service client classes from a web service WSDL (using something like the Axis library).  The web service interface will likely change infrequently, so you don't want to have the regeneration step reoccurring all the time in your main application build.  Create a separate project for this piece so that you only have to recreate the web service client classes when the WSDL changes.  Create a separate jar and use it in your main application.  This style also allows other projects to reuse these utility modules.

When following this style, you should place a version number in the jar manifest so that you can keep track of which applications are using which versions of your module.  Depending on how far you want to take this, you could also keep a text file in the jar that details the changes that have occurred for each revision (much like an open source library).

Answer (score 0):

It's all possible (we had the same situation some years ago). How hard or easy it'll be depends on your IDE (refactoring, merging, organizing new project) and you build tool (deploying). We used IDEA as IDE and Ant as build tool and it wasn't too hard. One sunday (nobody working+committing), 2 people on one computer.

I'm not sure what you mean by

> "deploy only some of the packages in a jar"

I think you will need all of them at runtime, won't you? As I understood they depend on each other.

Comment: some of them depend on some of the others. Lets say we have packages A, B, and C. A dn c and B an c might relate. (in my opinion id deploy A B and C whether they wanted A or B